# Sum Even Numbers in Fibonacci Sequence in Python

Tags: python, fibonacci

I'm a newer programmer working with Python 3 and I'm not exactly sure what I could do to fix this code. I'm trying to print the sum of all the even values from the fib sequence so long as they are under the value `n`. I can get the fib sequence, just stumped on only adding the even values.

```
def even_fibonacci(n):
    total = 0
    a, b =  0, 1
    while b < n:
        a, b = b, a+b
        return sum([b if b % 2 == 0])

even_fibonacci(100)
```

Comment: please consider the following http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and paste your code directly in your question along with your attempts and error messages.

Comment: Update your question with the output you are getting and the output expected to avoid downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def even_fibonacci(n):
    total = 0
    a, b =  0, 1
    sum = 0 # default, as 0 is even
    while b < n:
        a, b = b, a+b
        if b%2 == 0:
            sum += b # keep adding b if it is even
    return sum

sum = even_fibonacci(100)
print(sum)
```

Comment: Downvote? I will improvise my answer if given the reason.

Comment: For me, it works: http://ideone.com/b4i6tj

Comment: This comes really close, I switched the if statement variable to a, as well as the sum += a , that fixed it. ( added a print statement in between for the b values and noticed they were too large and skipping numbers)